# TypeScript: extend built-in String type with arbitrary method

Tags: typescript

This TypeScript code works:

```
// works!

interface String {
  mystartswith: (str: string) => boolean;
}

String.prototype.mystartswith = function(test): boolean {
  return this.lastIndexOf(test, 0) === 0;
};

console.log('abcd'.mystartswith('abc')); // prints 'true'
```

It compiles and runs and does what you expect the equivalent JS code to do.

This code does not compile:

```
interface String {
  mystartswith: (str: string) => boolean; // there are errors on this line
}
String.prototype.mystartswith = function(test: string): boolean {
  return this.lastIndexOf(test, 0) === 0;
};

export class MyClass {
  constructor(public arg: string) {
      if (arg.mystartswith('/')) { // and errors on this line
          console.log('arg starts with /');
      }
    }
}
```

When I take the export keyword off that line, it then works and compiles. How do I declare a class that be used by another module but internally would use the String.prototype extension so I don't have to write ugly code like:

```
function String_mystartswith(that, test): boolean {
  return that.lastIndexOf(test, 0) === 0;
};
if (String_mystartswith('abcd', 'abc')) {
  console.log('Oh TypeScript, my TypeScript.');
}
```

I don't necessarily need to use this extension outside of this file, although that would be nice. **Also, I am deploying in an ES5 environment so I cannot use ES6 JavaScript with built-in String.startsWith, as far as I know**. And it would be nice to have a general way to patch up these shortcomings in the standard library as I go.

All of this getting-in-the-way-of-what-I-am-doing and side-questing is making me not love TypeScript as much as it deserves. Just compile my code, and not make me waste over an hour on 'abcd'.mystartswith('abc')!

---

EDIT: I am clarifying that I am not asking about .startsWith, the built-in ES6 method, but how to add my own, especially if they are missing in ES5. Arbitrary methods, as is easy to do in vanilla JavaScript. There are good syntactic reasons to do this, even if what I want can be accomplished with ugly bits of 'normal' functions.

Comment: I'm not sure since I don't have a typescript ide around, but does setting the type of the `string` to `String` work?

Comment: give args the type of any and it will let you use startsWith.

Comment: @PaulBGD that does not work. I believe the types are synonymous.

Comment: @BrianAllanWest I tried all manner of variations on your suggestion and I could not get anything to work. It would not even compile my definition for startswith (lowercase) or startsWith (upper, like new ES6), much less the call to arg.startswith or arg.startsWith

Comment: @JaredUpdike My bad, my responde was totally unrelated to your problem.

Comment: Why you extending standard interface I recommend make extension in own file and reference i tin files where need. I have similar trouble and moving extensions to own file every time helped me. I think it is a compiler bug.